# Passing multiple model data using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 tables as below:

**MatchDetails**:

```
MatchId MatchName TeamId1 TeamId2
1       Test      1       2
```

**TeamDetails**:

```
TeamId TeamName
1      MyTeam  
2      YourTeam
```

Now I want a list of all the matches.

In my `MatchController` what I am trying to do is:

```
CricketEntity db = new CricketEntity();

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetAllMatches()
{
     List<C_MatchDetails> listMatches = db.C_MatchDetails.ToList();

     return Json(new
     {
           success = "true",
           Message = "Data retrive successfully",
           ResposeData = listMatches
     },
     JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is returning only match details. I want the match details with the team details filled in it.

Something like:

```
MatchId MatchName TeamId1 TeamName1 TeamId2 TeamName2
1       Test      1       MyTeam    2       YourTeam
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It makes life a lot easier if you add **navigation properties** to the `MatchDetails` class.

If you set you set your `MatchDetails` class up as follows:

```
public class MatchDetails{
    public int MatchId { get; set; }
    public string MatchName { get; set; }
    public int TeamId1 { get; set; }
    public int TeamId2 { get; set; }
    public virtual TeamDetails Team1 { get; set; } // One new navigation property
    public virtual TeamDetails Team2 { get; set; } // Another new navigation property
}
```

And define the relationships in your context class using Fluent API as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MatchDetails>()
    .HasRequired(m => m.Team1)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.TeamId1);

modelBuilder.Entity<MatchDetails>()
    .HasRequired(m => m.Team2)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.TeamId2);
```

Then your LINQ becomes much simpler and requires no projections:

```
var listMatches = db.C_MatchDetails
  .Include(x => x.Team1)
  .Include(x => x.Team2)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: I am still getting an error or  "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'cricketModel.C_MatchDetails' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Team1'."

Which I have added in my MatchDetails class. Is there anything else I need to do.

Comment: Try marking the navigation properties as `virtual` (updated answer above), that should allow the navigation properties to be lazy loaded. Also check out Julie Lerman's post on [Loading Related Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx) which may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create stored procedure on the db that returns joined table. like this ->>

```
Select m.MatchId, m.MatchName, m.TeamId1, t.TeamName as TeamName1, m.TeamId2, t2.TeamName as TeamName2
from MatchDetails m inner join TeamDetails t on m.TeamId1=t.TeamId Inner join TeamDetails t2 on m.TeamId2=t2.TeamId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Include so EF brings back references to teams when you get the data, something like:

... db.C_MatchDetails.Include(x => x.Team1).Include (x => x.Team2).To list();

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
MatchDetails.Join(TeamDetails, x => new {x.TeamId , x.TeamId},
                     y => new {y.TeamId1 , y.TeamId2}, (x, y) => new 
{
x.name;
//////
////
});
```